# Distribution mean and standard deviation using scipy.stats

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was trying to get the mean and standard deviation for log-normal distribution, where mu=0.4104857306 and sigma=3.4070874277012617, and I am expecting mean=500 and std=600. I am unsure what I have done wrong. Here are the code:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
a = 3.4070874277012617
b = 0.4104857306
c = stats.lognorm.mean(a,b)
d = stats.lognorm.var(a,b)
e = np.sqrt(d)
print("Mean =",c)
print("std =",e)
```

And the outputs are here:

```
Mean = 332.07447304207903
sd = 110000.50047821256
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

Thank you for your help. I have checked and found out there were some calculation mistake. I can now get the mean=500 but still cannot get std=600. Here is the code that I have used:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import exp
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(z):
    mean = 500
    std = 600
    sigma = z[0]
    mu = z[1]
    f = np.zeros(2)
    f[0] = exp(mu + (sigma**2) / 2) - mean
    f[1] = exp(2*mu + sigma**2) * exp(sigma**2 - 1) - std**2
    return f
z = fsolve (f,[1.1681794012855686,5.5322865416282365])
print("sigma =",z[0])
print("mu =",z[1])
print(f(z))

sigma = 1.1681794012855686
mu = 5.5322865416282365
```

I have tried to check the result with my calculator, and I can get std=600 as required, I still get `853.5698320847896` with `lognorm.std(sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))`.

Comment: Check your calculation for standard deviation. I am getting 500 and something else (165831.240) when I fix your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`scipy.stats.lognorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) lognormal distribution is parameterised in a slightly unusual way, in order to be consistent with the other continuous distributions. The first argument is the shape parameter, which is your `sigma`. That's followed by the `loc` and `scale` arguments, which allow shifting and scaling of the distribution. Here you want `loc=0.0` and `scale=exp(mu)`. So to compute the mean, you want to do something like:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.stats import lognorm
>>> mu = 0.4104857306
>>> sigma = 3.4070874277012617
>>> lognorm.mean(sigma, 0.0, np.exp(mu))
500.0000010889041
```

Or more clearly: pass the `scale` parameter by name, and leave the `loc` parameter at its default of `0.0`:

```
>>> lognorm.mean(sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
500.0000010889041
```

As @coldspeed says in his comment, your expected value for the standard deviation doesn't look right. I get:

```
>>> lognorm.std(sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
165831.2402402415
```

and I get the same value calculating by hand.

To double check that these parameter choices are indeed giving the expected lognormal, I created a sample of a million deviates and looked at the mean and standard deviation of the log of that sample. As expected, those give me back values that look roughly like your original `mu` and `sigma`:

```
>>> samples = lognorm.rvs(sigma, scale=np.exp(mu), size=10**6)
>>> np.log(samples).mean()  # should be close to mu
0.4134644116056518
>>> np.log(samples).std(ddof=1)  # should be close to sigma
3.4050012251732285
```

---

In response to the edit: you've got the formula for the variance of a lognormal slightly wrong - you need to replace the `exp(sigma**2 - 1)` term with `(exp(sigma**2) - 1)`. If you do that, and rerun the `fsolve` computation, you get:

```
sigma = 0.9444564779275075
mu = 5.768609079062494
```

And with those values, you should get the expected mean and standard deviation:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import lognorm
>>> import numpy as np
>>> sigma = 0.9444564779275075
>>> mu = 5.768609079062494
>>> lognorm.mean(sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
499.9999999949592
>>> lognorm.std(sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
599.9999996859631
```

Rather than using `fsolve`, you could also solve analytically for `sigma` and `mu`, given the desired mean and standard deviation. This gives you more accurate results, more quickly:

```
>>> mean = 500.0
>>> var = 600.0**2
>>> sigma = np.sqrt(np.log1p(var/mean**2))
>>> mu = np.log(mean) - 0.5*sigma*sigma
>>> mu, sigma
(5.768609078769636, 0.9444564782482624)
>>> lognorm.mean(sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
499.99999999999966
>>> lognorm.std(sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
599.9999999999995
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have checked and found out there were some calculation mistake. I can now get the mean=500 but still cannot get std=600. And I have included the code in the edited post.

Comment: You have the wrong formula for the variance. Use `(exp(sigma**2) - 1)` in place of `exp(sigma**2 - 1)`.

Comment: What's the difference between them? coz it still gives the same result

Comment: @VincentN: For me, it gives the correct result with `exp(sigma**2) - 1`, and the wrong result with your original `exp(sigma**2 - 1)`. As to "what's the difference": `exp(x - 1)` and `exp(x) - 1` are different functions, in the same way that `(x - 1)**2` and `x**2 - 1` are different functions. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: Oh, I don't know why I somehow overlook about the bracket last night. It is now giving the correct answer. Thank you for your help.